# Wordpress 404 page how remove additional description

Tags: wordpress

I have my custom 404.php page, but in a left top corner I have "Page not found". [image]

I can't find, from where should be remove this additional description.

Comment: can you share the code in your 404.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not like, just if you have the 404 page, it will trigger if the file is not found. Seems you are not configured to display the 404 page correctly. Use any wordpress plugin to do the same.

Comment: I display my custom 404 page, but I want to remove this sign. This  picture is only a corner. My page inheritance from somewhere this sentence.

Comment: If you did not using the "page not found" text in your 404 page, then there may be an issue in the permalinks. Check the URL, whether you are pointing to the correct 404 page url. Also try saving the settings-> permalinks once.